# Will deserialization overwrite the current object?

Tags: java, serialization

What happens if I save (serialize) an object, modify unserialized object and then deserialize the object. Will a deserialized version of the object simply overwrite the modified one? Or do I have to delete existing object specifically (or do some other manipulations to ensure proper deserialization)?

**PS** Thank you for your replies. They really helped.

Comment: Deserialization produces a _new_ object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deserialize an object, you get to choose what to do with the deserialized Object reference that is returned. It doesn't effect any other objects in your class.

Say you had an object of type MyObjectType called programObject. To serialize this object, you could do the following:

```
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(
    new FileOutputStream("fileToWriteTo.dat");
```

This would setup the output stream to write to "fileToWriteTo.dat". Then, to serialize this object, you would do this:

```
outputStream.writeObject(programObject);
```

To get the object back into the program, create an input stream like so:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
    new FileInputStream("fileToWriteTo.dat");
```

The following code would deserialize an object from the given input stream and return it as type Object, (thus the cast to MyObjectType).

```
programObject = (MyObjectType) inputStream.readObject();
```

This would effectively overwrite programObject. If you didn't want to do that, you could simply save the read-in object to a new object:

```
MyObjectType newObject = (MyObjectType) inputStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization means to convert the current state of an `Object` into some other form. The serialized version is completely separate from the original object, so changes made to the original cannot affect the serialized version.

When you deserialize the object, you get a *new* object in the same state as the original when it was serialized.

The best way to understand this is with an example. Here we start with a list `[1, 2, 3]`, serialize the list, then modify the original list by adding `4`. When we deserialize the original we get a new list that only contains `[1, 2, 3]`. For simplicity, I have saved the object to a byte array, but I could easily have saved it to a file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a list
    List<Integer> original = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    // Serialize the list as a byte array
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    new ObjectOutputStream(baos).writeObject(original);
    byte[] serializedList = baos.toByteArray();

    // Modify the list
    original.add(4);

    // Deserialize the original
    Object newList = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedList)).readObject();

    // Print the 2 versions
    System.out.println(original);       // [1, 2, 3, 4]
    System.out.println(newList);        // [1, 2, 3]
}
```